# separate scala list based on matching pattern

Tags: scala

i have a list  of the following scala trait.  How can i separate the list into two, one containing only ValidatedSbcCommand objects and other only containing FailedValidationSbcCommand objects?

```
sealed trait SbcCommandorOrValidationError 
case class ValidatedSbcCommand(sbcCommand: SbcCommand) extends SbcC  ommandorOrValidationError
case class FailedValidationSbcCommand(sbcCommandError: SbcCommandError) extends SbcCommandorOr
```

Comment: Unless you are sure you cannot afford to make two passes over the list, the simplest way is just to call `collect` twice, once for each type. Unless you're writing a 3D shader or something, it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `partition` method on list.  It takes a predicate and produces a `(List, List)` The first list is for the true case the second is for false.

Comment: doesn't keep sub-type info

Comment: You can cast the lists to the appropriate type.

Comment: You *can*, but casting is always a bad idea and almost always  unnecessary  in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

```
 val result = originalList.foldRight(Tuple2(List[ValidatedSbcCommand](), List[FailedValidationSbcCommand]())){ (start, rest) =>
        start match {
          case a:ValidatedSbcCommand => (a::rest._1, rest._2)
          case b:FailedValidationSbcCommand => (rest._1, b::rest._2)
          case _ => rest
        }
    }
```

Then  `result._1` will give you a list of `ValidatedSbcCommand`, and `result._2` will give you a list of `FailedValidationSbcCommand`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using `partition` with pattern matching. Given `list` is of type `List[SbcCommandorOrValidationError]` and contains only `ValidatedSbcCommand`s and `FailedValidationSbcCommand`s, you can do this:

```
val (validatedCommands, failedCommands) = list.partition {
  case command: ValidatedSbcCommand => true
  case _ => false
}
```

This will return a tuple of type `(List[SbcCommandorOrValidationError], List[SbcCommandorOrValidationError])` where the first list is all the `ValidatedSbcCommand`s and the second is all the `FailedValidationSbcCommand`s.

If you need to access the specific subclass later on, don't cast. Use pattern matching as above:

```
validatedCommands.map { 
  case c: ValidatedSbcCommand => functionTakingValidatedSbcCommandsOnly(c) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Scala 2.13, you can use of [`partitionMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#partitionMap[A1,A2](f:A=%3EEither[A1,A2]):(CC[A1],CC[A2])), which does exactly what you want, keeping the subtype info:

```scala
 list partitionMap {
    case v: ValidatedSbcCommand => Left(v)
    case f: FailedValidationSbcCommand => Right(f)
 }
```